# При ручном изменении разрешений приложение перезапускается

Tags: android, android-permissions

Если во время работы приложения переключиться в системные настройки android, зайти в "разрешения" включить и снова выключить какое-нибудь разрешение, затем вернуться в приложение, то приложение сделает перезапуск на том же месте(только данные не сохраняются, скорее всего приложение упадет), но хотелось бы чтобы открывалось заново, со стартовой активности, которая является splash, так по крайней мере реализовано в некоторых известных приложениях. Может у кого есть статья или код, как отследить, что поменяли разрешения и приложение надо пересоздать.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на [англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437339/how-to-restart-the-app-in-android-marshmallow-when-permission-changed-manually). В кратце, ответ: отследить нельзя. Вы должны сами сохранять нужные данные и восстанавливать при пересоздании приложения.

Comment: В приложениях instagram, лайфхакер как-то отлавливают момент краха приложения и открывают приложение прям со splash.

Comment: Вы уверены, что в этих приложениях отлавливается только изменение разрешений? Скорее всего они убиваются при любой смене конфигурации. Поэтому в англ. ответе и сказанно, что конкретно изменение разрешений отследить нельзя.

Comment: Вот мне бы тоже отлавливать любую смену конфигурации и я бы запустил приложение с самого начала. У вас есть идеи ?

Comment: Проверьте, должен вызываться метод `onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)` при пересоздании активити.